# Mobile phone Android app with Delphi or Lazarus

Tags: android, delphi, lazarus

Using *smart mobile studio* to develop a mobile application, I figured out I also need *phone gap* for further deployment of the application to my mobile device.
If I only want to distribute my mobile app on my phone  is there any more simple way to create a mobile app? Can I do the same with Lazarus? Is it easier to bring the executable to an Android phone?

Comment: Did you read the FreePascal and Lazarus documentation? Did you do a websearch?

Answer (score 2):

There is initial android target support in the development version FPC. There is afaik no lazarus support.

Two ways even, one by generating JVM code, one the native route. (native libraries used by a Java skeleton).

The latter one (native) seems to be the most used one.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Lazarus to compile for ARM processors which are in some mobile devices.

Read about it [here](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Setup_Cross_Compile_For_ARM)

Comment: This question asks about Android. It does not ask about *some mobile devices*.

Comment: The question doesn't ask about targeting a specific processor; it asks about targeting a specific *operating system* (Android), which runs on several different processors. This is not an answer to the question asked.

Comment: well thanks for that, how about rather than tearing my answer apart you provide one of your own?